# Need to fire an alert after "page load" on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a WordPress site and I have a template that renders all posts in a list at this URL `http://www.example.com/articles`. When the user clicks on a post title, it loads the content of the post using the same template but with a different URL `http://www.example.com/articles/?article_id=298`. What I cannot figure out is how to show an alert after the page loads the post content. I've tried `setTimeout`, `$(document).ready`, `$(window).load`, `window.onload=funtion()`, and now `$(document).on("pagecontainerload",function()`.

JQuery/JavaScript

```
    $('a.open-alert').click(function() {
      $(document).on("pagecontainerload",function(){
          window.alert('hey');
      });
    });
```

HTML

```
            <?php
                $tearsheet = get_query_var('article_id');
                if($tearsheet != '') {
                    echo 'there is something here';
                } else {

                    $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    );

                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    if($query->have_posts()) :
                        while($query->have_posts()) :
                            $query->the_post();
                ?>
                            <div>
                                <?php $id = get_the_ID(); ?>
                                <?php $title = get_the_title(); ?>
                                <a class="open-alert" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); echo '/find-articles/?article_id='.$id; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
                            </div>
                <?php
                        endwhile;
                    endif;
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Is the entire page reloaded (using the URL in the href-attribute) when the open-alert link is clicked?

Comment: Yes, entire page is reloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `click` handler will never be executed, since the page unloads and a new page is loaded - the one in the link `<a class="open-alert" href="<?php bloginfo...`. You may have a `return false` in the onclick handler, but that would mean, the link will not be executed.

In order to do this dynamically, consider reloading only the container within that page, containing the post text by some Ajax functionality.

Comment: thank you! Works perfectly. I'm still new so I can't vote yet but thanks so much.